# How do I configure a python server for POST?

Tags: python, httpserver

I'm trying out some PHP on my pc and made a little python server to host the files, one problem:
It can't do POST, I always get the error 501. I've heard that you can implement POST in these servers, but I didn't find how to do this, can someone help?

Here's my current server:

```py
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the script I personally use for when I need this kind of functionality:

```py
#!/usr/env python3
import http.server
import os
import logging

try:
    import http.server as server
except ImportError:
    # Handle Python 2.x
    import SimpleHTTPServer as server

class HTTPRequestHandler(server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    """
    SimpleHTTPServer with added bonus of:

    - handle PUT requests
    - log headers in GET request
    """

    def do_GET(self):
        server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
        logging.warning(self.headers)

    def do_PUT(self):
        """Save a file following a HTTP PUT request"""
        filename = os.path.basename(self.path)

        # Don't overwrite files
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            self.send_response(409, 'Conflict')
            self.end_headers()
            reply_body = '"%s" already exists\n' % filename
            self.wfile.write(reply_body.encode('utf-8'))
            return

        file_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
            output_file.write(self.rfile.read(file_length))
        self.send_response(201, 'Created')
        self.end_headers()
        reply_body = 'Saved "%s"\n' % filename
        self.wfile.write(reply_body.encode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.test(HandlerClass=HTTPRequestHandler)
```

But perhaps a more fitting, and simpler script would be the following, as found on [Flavio Copes' blog](https://flaviocopes.com/python-http-server/):

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        message = "Hello, World! Here is a GET response"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        message = "Hello, World! Here is a POST response"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))

with HTTPServer(('', 8000), handler) as server:
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: How to send data in Above Post request ?

Comment: @PradeepPadmanabanC Many ways! The simplest command-line way of doing it is using cURL: [cURL POST examples](https://www.warp.dev/terminus/curl-post-request)